# FirehoseDestination - Could not assume IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am getting following error while Setting up a kinesis data firehose event destination for Amazon SES event publishing using terraform. It seems like the terraform created the IAM role but throwing the error while creating the firehose event destination with IAM role.
Whereas able to attach same IAM role with firehose event destination from AWS console which was created by terraform.
If I manually create the same IAM role using AWS console and then pass the ARN of the role to the terraform it works. However if I try to create the role using terraform and then create the event destination it doesn’t work. Can someone pls help me on this.

```
Error creating SES configuration set event destination: InvalidFirehoseDestination: Could not assume IAM role <arn:aws:iam::<AWS account name >:role/<AWS IAM ROLE NAME>>.
```

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ses_configuration_set_assume_role" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ses.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ses_firehose_destination_policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "firehose:PutRecord",
      "firehose:PutRecordBatch"
    ]

    resources = [
     "<ARN OF AWS FIREHOSE DELIVERY STREAM >"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ses_firehose_destination_iam_policy" {
  name   = "SesfirehosedestinationPolicy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ses_firehose_destination_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ses_firehose_destination_role" {
  name                 = "SesfirehosedestinationRole"
  assume_role_policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ses_configuration_set_assume_role.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ses_firehose_destination_role_att" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ses_firehose_destination_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ses_firehose_destination_iam_policy.arn
}


resource "aws_ses_configuration_set" "create_ses_configuration_set" {
  name = var.ses_config_set_name
}

resource "aws_ses_event_destination" "ses_firehose_destination" {
  name                   = "event-destination-kinesis"
  configuration_set_name = aws_ses_configuration_set.create_ses_configuration_set.name
  enabled                = true
  matching_types         = ["send", "reject", "bounce", "complaint", "delivery", "renderingFailure"]
  depends_on             = [aws_iam_role.ses_firehose_destination_role] 
  kinesis_destination {
    stream_arn = "<ARN OF AWS FIREHOSE DELIVERY STREAM>"
    role_arn  = aws_iam_role.ses_firehose_destination_role.arn
  }
}
```

Comment: You already have an implicit dependency on the IAM role, so you probably don't need to use `depends_on`. Can you drop that line and try running the plan/apply again?

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks for you reply. Yes I have removed the depends on and tried it. But no luck.

Comment: Form the docs it seems you are missing a `condition` in the `ses_configuration_set_assume_role` resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/event-publishing-add-event-destination-firehose.html#event-publishing-add-event-destination-firehose-role. In other words, I think you need to fix the trust policy.

Comment: @MarkoE If I manually create the same IAM role using AWS console and then pass the ARN of the role to the terraform it works. However if I try to create the role using terraform and then create the event destination it doesn’t work.

Comment: Is STS enabled in the region you are trying to use SES in? I found an AWS forum post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=288005.

Comment: Disregard the last comment, it obviously is because it works when defined manually.

Comment: Are you sure that the role created in AWS console is exactly same?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes STS is enabled for the region to which am trying to use SES. I also went through the link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=288005. But no luck.

Comment: @Marcin Yes the role is same which I am trying to create via terraform and which I have created manually both are same.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to look at your Firehose datasource.  If it is a Kinesis Datastream, it will not work.  It will only work when using a Direct PUT and other datasource for the Kinesis Firehose.  I ran into this issue while setting this up for my Kinesis Firehose to Datadog as well.  I hope that this helps.

Comment: The firehose datasource is "Direct PUT" only. Even though  am facing same issue. It took AWS support as well. They also verified my datasource type. It was "Direct Put" only.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue and was able to resolve it with a slight workaround.

The issue is likely due to the time it takes AWS to propagate the IAM role to all the regions. As an IAM role is global, it will be created first in a 'random' region and then propagated to all regions. So if it is not first created in your region it may take some time to propagate and you will get this error if the SES Event Destination is created before the IAM role has propagated.

It does not help to add a depends_on clause, as terraform (correctly?) thinks the IAM role has been created, it has just not been propagated to your region yet.

The solution that worked for me was to create an IAM role that grants access to the "sts:AssumeRole" action for the SES service and the "firehose:PutRecordBatch" action for the Firehose.  When I apply the Terraform, I did a targeted apply first for only this role, waited a minute (to allow the IAM role to propagate) and then do a normal terraform apply to complete.

In your example the command will look something like this:

```
terraform apply --target aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.ses_firehose_destination_role_att
terraform apply
```